# Запускаю скрипт,выдаёт TypeError:Cannot Use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сам код скрипта

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import zlib
import sys
import re
import binascii


if(len(sys.argv) < 2 or sys.argv[1] == "-h"):
    print("usage: python DecompNewDell.py <biosupdate.exe>")
    exit()


f = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")

string = f.read()

pat = re.compile(r'.{4}\xAA\xEE\xAA\x76\x1B\xEC\xBB\x20\xF1\xE6\x51.{1}\x78\x9C')


match = pat.search(string)

(start_match, end_match) = match.span()
compessed_len = string[start_match:start_match+4]

compessed_len = binascii.b2a_hex(compessed_len[::-1])
compessed_len = long(compessed_len, 16)
f.seek(start_match+16)
string = f.read(compessed_len)

o = zlib.decompress(string)

f2 = open(sys.argv[1] + "_decompressed.hdr", "wb")
f2.write(o)
f.close()
f2.close()
print("Decompressed data written to %s_decompressed.hdr" % sys.argv[1])
```

Выполняю с командной строки(файл находится рядом со скриптом,а именно на рабочем столе и он `.exe`) и в итоге он бьёт тревогу на строке `match = pat.search(string)`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если работаете с бинарными данными, то и паттерн нужно задавать в байтах

```
pat = re.compile(rb'.{4}\xAA\xEE\xAA\x76\x1B\xEC\xBB\x20\xF1\xE6\x51.{1}\x78\x9C')
```